# How to simply join n-to-n association in rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have three tables: `users`, `locations`, `locations_users`, The associations are as follows :

```
user has_many locations_users
user has_many locations :through => locations_users

location has_many locations_users
location has_many users :through => locations_users
```

How would I find all the users who are joined to location_id = 5 in one query?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. It fetches all data from the left table with matching data from right, if present (if not present, join column is null):

```
User
  .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN locations_users ON locations_users.user_id = users.id')
  .where('locations_users.id IS NULL OR locations_users.location_id = ?', 5)
  .all
```

Hovewer:

- this query uses `join`, which's performance can be poor on big tables (maybe two queries will perform faster - test it!)
- for better performance, make sure, that indexes are set on joined columns

Comment: You probably mean `OR` instead of `AND` in the criteria.

Comment: This answer is the best fit for the question but the left join is slow as hell...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know 1 query way but the solution below is efficient.

```
a = User.where("id NOT IN (?)", LocationUser.pluck("DISTINCT user_id"))
b = LocationUser.where(location_id: 5).pluck("DISTINCT user_id")
result = User.where(id: a+b)
```